# How to rebuild VS2010 IDE Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

some are working some are not working.

for example,

i did

```
using System.Web.Security;

MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
        string UserID = myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        Response.Write(UserID);
```

the membershipuser is not highlighted in green. and System.Web. is not listing objects

but the code is working fine though. How do I make the intellisense work fine?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try resetting your Intellisense cache, `Edit`>`Intellisense`>`Clear local cache`.

Or try nuking it - delete your [SolutionName].sdf and .suo files

Edit:

VS 2010 equivalent is `Project`>`Rescan Solution`

Comment: Edit>Intellisense>Clear local cache option is not avaialble in my copy of VS 2010

Comment: Make sure your currently editing text in the code editor. If you last selected a project in the Solution Explorer, for example, the option won't appear.

Comment: Tried that no joy. Option still is'nt there.

Comment: I think the VS 2010 eqivalelent is Project>Rescan Solution

Comment: I added the menu item from customizations menu, but its disabled.going for nuke...

Answer (score 4):

I'm using VS2010 and `Project` > `Rescan Solution` seems to do the trick, although it seems to take longer than normal. I suppose it's because it is rebuilding the entire cache, rather than selectively updating parts of it.

If you're using VsVim or other non-default keybinds, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> still does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If the cs file's build action is not set to compile, that will also cause the Intellisense to not work within that file.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is to use the following at the command line (or Start->Run):

devenv /resetuserdata

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2005, but, I found that, in order convince it to build intellisense for boost, I had to specify the explicit path to the boost includes - shades of 1988!  A relative path did not work.  Dunno how this is going to affect the team, might try the environment variable trick to see if that's a workaround this poor indexing implementation.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/fa8277f9-ecf0-40a6-8e0e-118e4615d5bc/intellisense-and-nonstandard-directories

Answer (score -1):

*I think the VS 2010 equivalent is Project>Rescan Solution –  tletnes Jan 21 '13 at 22:50*

This is what worked for me.