# Visual Studio Code IntelliSense removed classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've been used to [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) semi-broken [IntelliSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion#IntelliSense), where it only shows relevant methods in certain circumstances, but that one is driving me crazy. Every time I create a class, Visual Studio Code is able to find it. But once this class is deleted, it is STILL able to find it, even days after it's been deleted.

How do I fix that?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289936/refreshing-the-auto-completeintellisense-database-in-visual-studio

Comment: No it's not a duplicate unfortunately. This give an answer in visual studio, not visual studio code. May I ask why the downvote?

Comment: The downvote was based on the belief that this was a duplicate issue. I would not be surprised of VSCode worked in a similar fashion as VS, creating a database to store intellisense data. Find the file and kill it.

Comment: Can you please provide some example code along with the the expected and actual behavior.  It'd probably be best if you file this sort of issue on Github instead: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools or https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vscode stores intellisense informations in .BROWSE.VC.DB files. For some reasons I was able to find them in .vscode folder for some projects but not in others, even with default configuration. The location might have changed with recent versions. I found all .BROWSE.VC.DB in AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage. Deleted it and it worked.