# Suggestions/Autocompletion not working in VS Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble with VS Code, on my Windows laptop. I'm working on a CSS file and when I'm typing properties, it used to have a dialog box that would show suggestions, and even some information on the properties themselves, about what they do etc. That does not happen anymore. I've tried searching the net with no luck. Tried going in the app settings, looking under editor and have it set like this:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": false,
  "strings": false
}
```

I have even uninstalled and completely reinstalled the program with no luck. My Windows desktop copy of VS Code works fine and as intended.

What would be causing this?

Comment: Does VSC on your desktop have any extensions installed? Perhaps https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css

Comment: Same as on my laptop. Just some themes, JSHint and such. i have that one you referenced installed on both already.

Comment: clean solution->rebuild->restart. Or if c++ try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289936/refreshing-the-auto-complete-intellisense-database-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Follow these commands: [stable version of vs code]

1. ctrl + ,
2. User > Extensions > Emmet
3. Syntax Profiles > Edit in settings.json
4. Make sure these are true in the following picture:[Emmet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeEbH.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

open your VS code then open extensions by `ctrl + shift + x`.
Enter the name of the programming language you want to be supported in VS.
in your case, this should do the work:

[image]