# jQuery IntelliSense Stopped Working in VS2019

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, intellisense, visual-studio-2019, mdbootstrap

I have a large .NET Core 2.0 project which uses jQuery. **All jQuery in the project works perfectly fine during run-time.**

However, something changed that caused my jQuery IntelliSense to stop working in VS2019 (regardless of typing "jQuery" or the "$" shorthand in my code). I unfortunately cannot locate the change.

[image]

My jquery.js/jquery.min.js files are located in wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist and referenced throughout the site in _Layout.cshtml.

According to [the VS2019 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2019):

> By default, the Salsa language service will try to detect which JavaScript libraries are in use and automatically download and reference the corresponding .d.ts file that describes the library in order to provide richer IntelliSense. The files are downloaded to a cache located under the user folder at %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\TypeScript.

...and yes, jQuery is there as expected:

[image]

I've tried restarting VS2019 and my PC, batch clean/rebuild and resetting the JavaScript/Typescript checkboxes in the options and [refreshing the Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289936/refreshing-the-auto-complete-intellisense-database-in-visual-studio) by deleting the .vs folder and restarting.

*Note that JavaScript IntelliSense is working as expected.*

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade your vs 2019 to latest release version?Does it happen when you create a new asp.net core 2.2 or higher project?

Comment: VS2019 is fully updated, and I was able to create a new Core 3.0 project using the out-of-the-box MVC template with functional jQuery intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue to be with including the [MDBootsrap Pro (jQuery Version) Library](https://mdbootstrap.com/products/jquery-ui-kit/) in my project. Once I removed the library and re-added it, the IntelliSense worked again.

I remain uncertain whether this was caused by a script conflict or simply an overload of script for the IntelliSense to try to sort through.

Adding MDBootstrap tag to the question in case it helps anyone else in the future.

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for sharing the useful info and please accepting it as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)