# Visual Studio remembers deleted includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, header, include

I have a dll C++ project in Visual Studio 2017. I was changing the includes, libs, adding additional paths n VC++ directories, now I seems to clean everything - in VC++ directories in project properties, in al h and cpp files - there are quite a few of them. But still project somehow remembers previously used includes and when I click F12 on the class, that is defined in two headers (but with different namespaces), it opens "old" header, that is not included anymore, despite it's written propernamespace::classname, it jumps to the file where it is differentnamespace::classname.

Though this header isn't listed in the "External Dependencies" in the Solution Explorer. Nor in the vcxproj file. How to make my project to forget not included at the moment headers?

Comment: Might be related to [refreshing-the-auto-complete-intellisense-database-in-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289936/refreshing-the-auto-complete-intellisense-database-in-visual-studio).

Comment: Have you set both `x86` and `x64`, or `Debug` and `Release` modes?

Comment: @BarrnetChou ye, I've checked all those

Comment: Is there any error message? If so, could you show it? If you could show the `Properties` settings of VS, including `VC++ Directories`,  `C/C++->Genreal` and `Linker->Input`, it will help solve the problem.