# C++ IntelliSense is pointing to an incorrect version of included library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I have a `C++` static library project that compiles without any errors, nor it shows any errors in the `Error list` window. So all seems to be working OK. Except that when I try to open the source (`CTRL` + left click on a library or library specific item), then the file of an incorrect version is opened. Why?

To elaborate. I have `CUDA 9.1`, `CUDA 9.2` and `CUDA 10.2` installed on my `PC`. My project has following `CUDA Linker` config:

- Additional Libary Directories: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\lib\x64;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
- Additional Dependencies:  cudart.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

In the `CUDA linker`'s  `Command line` I have:

> "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink -o x64\Debug\Core3.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc  /nologo  /Zi   " -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\lib\x64" cudart.lib

In the `CUDA C/C++`'s `Command line` I have:

[image]

**So, it looks OK.** But in the code, when I click on any of the includes - they point to `9.2` source. Example:

```
#include <cuda.h> 
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
```

the path is: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\ **v9.2** \include

[image]
[image]

Furthermore I have checked the environment variables. All good. Also checked which `props` files are used in `.vcxproj` file. Properties `CUDA 10.2.props` are used everywhere.

So my question is - why does the `IntelliSence` still thinks that I am using an older version of `CUDA`? And more importantly - how do I make him use a proper, `10.2` version?

**EDIT 1:** more information requested in comments. Include directories - defaults used.

[image]
[image]
[image]
Variable check: [image]
[image]

Comment: You did not show configured include dir - from your VS solution or directly your VS installation. Seems that one of these is pointing to 9.2 version.

Comment: @Neywat could you elaborate on `or directly your VS installation`? Where should I check? Regarding the first - I have edited the post and attached Include Directories config, if that is what you meant. Defaults are used.

Comment: By ```VS installation```, I was refering to _options_ dialog > _VC++ Directories_. If your project don't override paths, then they are the same. For your project, does ```C/C++``` item or ```CUDA C/C++``` item have other include paths configured ?

Comment: @Neywat by convention defaults are used in places that I have not mentioned in original post. :) As a proof - see edit. I have attached multiple pictures from the project settings, including these that you have asked about. Please check. **p.s. stackoverflow community/mods please don't ban me if there are too many pictures..**

Comment: Sorry for that, I was checking the obvious :). I suppose you tried to delete the intellisense database (saved my life couple of times). If you use precompiled headers, it can also cause strange behavior.

Comment: @Neywat no I have not.. Just checked the internet - perhaps you meant the `.vs` folder? I will try this approach within a hour and then report back. :)

Comment: @Neywat hey, it worked! I have posted an answer. If you want to - you can post the answer instead and I will remove mine.. I just want this question to stay as there might be other people struggling with the same situation.. If you could add some useful information about the `intellisense` and/or the `.vs` folder then I and other people would be very glad. :) Thank you for help!

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I found 2 related questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289936/refreshing-the-auto-complete-intellisense-database-in-visual-studio and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830397/how-to-rebuild-vs2010-ide-intellisense. Maybe your question can be marqued as duplicate ?

Comment: They have one thing in common - issue with the IntelliSense. The clues are different. Case 1 - auto-complete stops working after X number of code. case 2 - IS not working for one particular case. In my case - all code is highlighted and autocomplete works fine. Only the wrong sources are showed. While I agree that the problem is the same old IS (or VisualStudio?), the rest is different and therefore is not a duplicate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Neywat has suggested removing the `IntelliSense` folder and it worked.

I had to remove the whole `.vs` folder in solution directory though.

The question remains though - is this a known issue and is the Microsoft team aware of it? What are the recommendations in regards to `.vs` folder lifetime? Should we clean-it up from time to time?